# getExternalFilesDirs() : How do we write to external sd card for android 4.4 and above in Adobe Air App?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, external, sd-card

We are making an app in adobe air in which we want to save files downloaded from our server. We would prefer that this is stored to the external sd card since the file size is big.

According to this link - ((http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#AccessingExtFiles))  since Android 4.4 - we dont need any permission to write to your apps = private directories.
We have been able to store the downloaded files to the "external partition" of internal memory. We want to be able to store the files on "external sd card" if it exists.

There is a function - getExternalFilesDirs() which enables this . What is the alternate function in Adobe Air (actionscript 3.0) to run this function?

Comment: To be clear, getExternalFilesDir() does not do what you want. It will return the external partition of internal memory, that you say you can already do.

Comment: You can access File.getRootDirectories and see which `mnt` volumes are available or which `storage/emulated` are returned

Comment: `To be clear, getExternalFilesDir() does not do what you want. `. @Tom Wijgers. He said already so and was talking about a different function:`getExternalFilesDirs()`. So there are more external files dirS.

Comment: You are right, I did not notice the s

Comment: It is mentioned in the above link that getExternalFilesDirs() 'function with s' returns a File array with two entries in which first entry is primary external storage and the second is secondary external storage.I want to know the actionscript 3.0 equivalent function.

Comment: I think (I didn't tested that) that for non rooted android device, `File.desktopDirectory`, `File.documentsDirectory` and `File.userDirectory` will all point to your external storage (when it's available of course). You can also request to your user to select the path where you will save your data and use that, you can inform him that you recommend the use of an external storage ...

Comment: I have tested it on android device. File.userDirectory, File.documentsDirectory, File.desktopDirectory all points to internal storage.I want to write data to external sdcard folder.